Telegram Mini App with NGROK custom domain results in white screen, while using randomly generated url works perfectly
I'm programming telegram bot with mini app, for which I'm trying to use secured page from ngrok. I start the ngrok site with command "ngrok http --domain= 8000", it starts, when I access it, it runs perfectly: all js and css files were loaded. However, when I try to access it from telegram mini app, I receive white screen, because css and js files were not loaded. I screenshot what was loaded instead of them. screenshot
Anyway, I tried using randomly generated ngrok page, which I start with command "ngrok 8000", and when I access it from either Telegram Mini App or browser, js and css load perfectly.
Can anyone help with custom domain issue, please?
i tried googling the issue, but I didnt find anyone with similar issue
